# Managing different publish profiles for each developers in SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

In our current dev. workflow there is main database --> *DbMain*. There is the process that takes the latest version of the project and automatically deploys it there and after that it triggers unit tests. As we would like to always have working version of the project in the source control each developer should be sure that he checks in the working code and all tests would be passed.

For this purpose we decided to create individual databases for each developers that has following naming convention --> *DbMain_**XX*** (where ***XX*** are the developers initial). So every developer before the check-in is suppose to publish all the changes to that database manually and run the unit tests. It is useful to setup publish config for this purpose with that is the copy of the main publish config with the only difference in the database names.

That would introduce that we will have a lot of different publish profiles in the solution that is quite a mess.

If we will not add these profiles to the source control, then *.sqlproj* file would still have reference to these files so the project will have reference to the not existing files.

So the actual question. Can I have single publish profile for all developers where the database name will be changed using variables? For example *DbName_$(dev_initials)*? Or can we have that each developer would have their own publish configs only locally and it wouldn't break the project?

UPDATE:

According to the Peter Schott comments:

I can create local publish profile, but if I don't add it to the source control, then the still be an entry in sqlproj file, but the file itself will be unavailable.

Running tests locally have at least 2 disadvantages. The first one is that everybody is supposed to install SQL Server locally. We are mainly working via virtual machines and the disk space is quite limited there. Another thing is that developers will definitely forget or not will not run tests manually every time. Sometimes they will push changes to the repo without building it or/and running tests. We would like to avoid such situations and "catch" failed build as soon as possible.

Another approach that was mentioned is to have 1 common build database. And in my case we have one (DbMain). All of developers can use it for it's needs but we will definitely catch the situation when the 2 developers will publish at the same time and that can make a lot of confusion by figuring out what's really went wrong.

Comment: You can definitely create publish profiles locally to not break the project, but would it make more sense to build locally and run tests there or have a common build database with the checkin/commit that broke the build raise the flag rather than creating one DB per person?  (Don't make this a DB that contains critical data - just something that builds or doesn't, maybe with test data first.)

Comment: @PeterSchott I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to this kind of thing - not only for SSDT publish profiles but for config files in general - is to commit a generic version of the file with a name something like `DbMain.publish.xml.template`, and provide instructions to the developer to rename the file to `DbMain.publish.xml` - or whatever - and `.gitignore` this local copy of the file, allowing the developers to make whatever changes they want, but inherit the common settings from the `.template` version of the file.

Publish profiles don't need to be added to the `.sqlproj` to be used at deploy time, this is merely a convenience in Visual Studio to make them easier to find and edit, so you don't need to worry about broken references.

You are right in wanting to avoid multiple developers publishing to a common "build" database, this is a recipe for frustration.

Really, you want the "build" database to be published to as part of your CI process, meaning *after* the developers have pushed their changes.

Comment: Currently I did in the similar way, but with the exception that I've pushed the "shared" version of the config file and then every developer should say to git not to track the changes for that file

Comment: Yeah, so you are already on the right track. If the only problem you have now is broken references in the `.sqlproj` file, then all you need to do is tell the developers not to add their local config files to the project.

Comment: there is no broken reference in the config as I've pushed it to the git and then everybody is supposed to say not to track local changes. It is almost the same as you suggest, the difference is that you are not pushing this config to the git

Comment: OK, so if the only problem you have is that the `sqlproj` has references to missing files, then you can avoid this by not adding the individual publish profiles to the project.